# Java Superpose two JPanels

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

I'm working on Java 7 for a desktop application using mostly swing.

I would like to Superpose two `JPanels`. Basically, I have a `JPanel` (1) in which I would like to draw some stuff (with `paintComponent()`) and on top of it, I'd like to display another `JPanel` (2) filled with a `JScrollPane` (3) filled with a `Jtable` (4).

The Components (2, 3 & 4) would have a transparent background to let see the painted Component on the `JPanel` 1.

Any idea how to organize/do/implement this ?

Thank you !

Comment: Set the layout manager of the bottom panel to BorderLayout, add the second to it, probably also using a BorderLayout

Comment: You could also take a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13677850/add-background-image-in-jtable/13678077#13678077) for some ideas

Comment: Have you tried using JXPanel? it goes with separate library for swing and has a opacity property. To make this work you would probably need to set opacity of both panels to 0.5 so that they would overlay each other and everything is visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the proper way.

My Jpanel (1) is a borderLayout and has a paintComponent(gg) method which draw several things.
I add to that panel a JScrollPane (3) and inside it a Jtable (4).

The idea is that 3 & 4 have a transparent background.

For a JScrollpane and a JPanel:

- jp.setOpaque(false)

For a JTable, it is more difficult. The background of the JT has to be opaque and the background of each cell has to be transparent using R,G,B,A. To make it opaque, precess as with a Jpanel. Then add a CellRenderer to the JTable and (for each cell) setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));

I then had some issues when I scrolled in the ScrollPane. You will have to add a visibility listener to the JScrollPane. When to JScrollPane visibility change, repaint() the Jpanel (1).

This way it's workings but it's not fluid. Even with a new generation untrabook(2014).
(I only draw an image from a file in the Jpanel 1)

So, I hope there will be some better solutions.

Update : see this : [Add background image in JTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13677850/add-background-image-in-jtable/13678077#13678077)