# JTable becomes opaque even if specified otherwise, because of DefaultTableModel getColumnClass overrides

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable

My project requires that a table be drawn as transparent to reveal an image underneath. When I override the function `getColumnClass` in `DefaultTableModel`, it seems like `table.setOpaque(false)` no longer does anything. I need each cell to only draw images within, which works fine. Here is the table model:

```
JTable table = new JTable(model) {
            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                //all cells false
                return false;
            }
            @Override
            public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
                return ImageIcon.class;
            }
        };
```

There is a small portion of the table visible while scrolling, but the moment the table updates when I move it around or click on it, it becomes opaque.

I have a simple goal, where i am to overlay a translucent image in a cell, over an image underneath the table, as if like a selection. The image would toggle off and on and is handled in this mouse adapter:

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    int row = table.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());//get mouse-selected row
    int col = table.columnAtPoint(e.getPoint());//get mouse-selected col

    String string = row+"|"+col;

    if(selectedCells.contains(string)){
    
        //cell was already selected, deselect it
        selectedCells.remove(string);
        table.setValueAt(null, row, col);
        System.out.println("Removed Cell " + string);
        
    } else {
    
        //cell was not selected
        selectedCells.add(string);
        table.setValueAt(PrimaryWindow.selection, row, col);
        System.out.println("Added Cell " + string);
    }
}
```

I paint the image underneath by overriding the panel the table is in, which looks like this:

```
JPanel background = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() )
        {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
            {
                super.paintComponent(g);

                g.drawImage(icon.getImage(), 0, 0, scale*32, scale*32, this);
            }
        };
```

And then add the table in above: `background.add(table);`

I do have this set:

```
DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer = (DefaultTableCellRenderer)table.getDefaultRenderer(Object.class);
        renderer.setOpaque(false);
```

And this set:

```
table.setOpaque(false);
```

[Here is what the wrong, but current output looks like after clicking a bunch of places](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bukcl.png)

[Here is what it looks like if i remove the custom renderer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ot3IB.png)

[Here is what it should look like (i made it in paint)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiaWB.png)

Simply clicking the mouse does put an image inside the table at the cell I click, which is exactly what I want, as well as removing it upon clicking the same spot again. However, it is useless until I can see what is underneath. How can I have the table be transparent, and also display my images over the panel underneath?

EDIT:
Here is a scratch file with the problem in full display. Replace the

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.LinkedList;

class Scratch {

    static LinkedList<String> selectedCells = new LinkedList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(512,512);

        //Make a red square
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(1,1, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
        image.setRGB(0,0, Color.RED.getRGB());

        //Scale it to the size of the window
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image.getScaledInstance(512, 512, 1));

        image.setRGB(0,0, new Color(0x49000000, true).getRGB());

        ImageIcon selection =  new ImageIcon(image.getScaledInstance(16, 16, 1));

        Object[][] data = new Object[32][32];
        String[] names = new String[32];
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, names);


        JTable table = new JTable(model) {
            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                //all cells false
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
                //Removing 'ImageIcon.class' and replacing it with 'Object.class' makes the table transparent, however does not display the image.
                //Keeping this now allows us to put in images into the table, but removes the red square from the background and makes the table opaque
                return ImageIcon.class;
            }
        };
        //Set the entire table to transparent
        table.setOpaque(false);
        //Set the renderer to transparent also
        DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer = (DefaultTableCellRenderer)table.getDefaultRenderer(Object.class);
        renderer.setOpaque(false);

        MouseListener tableMouseListener = new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                int row = table.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
                int col = table.columnAtPoint(e.getPoint());

                String string = row+"|"+col;

                if(selectedCells.contains(string)){
                    //cell was already selected, deselect it
                    selectedCells.remove(string);
                    table.setValueAt(null, row, col);
                    System.out.println("Removed Cell " + string);
                }else{
                    //cell was not selected
                    selectedCells.add(string);
                    table.setValueAt(selection, row, col);
                    System.out.println("Added Cell " + string);
                }
                System.out.println(selectedCells);
            }
        };


        table.addMouseListener(tableMouseListener);
        table.setName("name");

        JPanel background = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() )
        {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
            {
                super.paintComponent(g);

                g.drawImage(icon.getImage(), 0, 0, 512, 512, this);
            }
        };
        background.setSize(512,512);
        frame.add(background);
        background.add(table);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13677850/add-background-image-in-jtable/13678077#13678077)

Comment: Consider providing a [mcve] which demonstrates your issue

Comment: @MadProgrammer I've updated the question. There is a fully self contained scratch file ready to run OOTB provided now

Comment: I had issues when ever I used your `JTable` extensions, I would suggest not doing that and make better use of the custom renderer support and the table model itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While playing around with your code, I had issues when ever I used your `JTable` extensions...

```
JTable table = new JTable(model) {
    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        //all cells false
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
        //Removing 'ImageIcon.class' and replacing it with 'Object.class' makes the table transparent, however does not display the image.
        //Keeping this now allows us to put in images into the table, but removes the red square from the background and makes the table opaque
        return ImageIcon.class;
    }
};
```

This kind of makes me cringe anyway.

If you want to change the class type of the cell, then you really should be doing this from the `TableModel`, that's its responsibility.

I'd also, personally, supply my own `TableCellRenderer`, this way I gain full control over it's functionality directly

For example...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Object[][] data = new Object[32][32];
                    String[] names = new String[32];
                    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, names) {
                        @Override
                        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                            return Icon.class;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                            return false;
                        }                        
                    };

                    JTable table = new JTable(model);
                    table.setOpaque(false);

                    table.setDefaultRenderer(Icon.class, new TransparentTableCellRenderer());

                    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
                    scrollPane.setOpaque(false);
                    scrollPane.getViewport().setOpaque(false);

                    LinkedList<String> selectedCells = new LinkedList<>();

                    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                    Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
                    g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
                    g2d.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
                    g2d.dispose();

                    Icon icon = new ImageIcon(img);

                    table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                        @Override
                        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                            int row = table.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
                            int col = table.columnAtPoint(e.getPoint());

                            String string = row + "|" + col;

                            if (selectedCells.contains(string)) {
                                //cell was already selected, deselect it
                                selectedCells.remove(string);
                                table.setValueAt(null, row, col);
                                System.out.println("Removed Cell " + string);
                            } else {
                                //cell was not selected
                                selectedCells.add(string);
                                table.setValueAt(icon, row, col);
                                System.out.println("Added Cell " + string);
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                    // Supply your own back ground image
                    frame.setContentPane(new BackgroundPane(ImageIO.read(Main.class.getResource("/images/Mando01.jpeg"))));
                    frame.add(scrollPane);
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public class TransparentTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
            setOpaque(false);
            if (value instanceof Icon) {
                setIcon((Icon)value);
            } else {
                setIcon(null);
            }
            return this;
        }

    }

    public class BackgroundPane extends JPanel {

        private Image background;

        public BackgroundPane(Image background) {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            this.background = background;
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return background == null ? new Dimension(200, 200) : new Dimension(background.getWidth(this), background.getHeight(this));
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.drawImage(background, 0, 0, this);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }
}
```